# Data get render on Desktop Excel using office.js, but on Chrome Office 365 its give an error "There was an error processing the request."

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, office365api

We are using **Office js** library to render data on excel. There are more than **2000 rows** that works fine on **Desktop Excel**.
But when same **API** is used on **Chrome office 365** it gives error message **"There was an error processing the request."**

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

As data get larger Chrome Office excel is not able to render data.
Please help us as this is blocker in our application and our production is getting effected.

Comment: I guess you are hitting payload size limit, what's the size for a single row?

Comment: I am receiving like below response object format in Ajax call. 
{"resultRow":[{"Date":"2019-05-01T05:00:00.000+0000","Class of ":"0","Account ID (FA)":"123","Account":"ABC","Account2":"PQR"} ...]
And having around 2000 of rows in resultRow array.
Each row object contains around 4-6 columns.
Same trying to render on excel using Excel.run function of Office js.
@RaymondLu

Comment: Can you try to split the operation and see if you still hit the error?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 limitations when interacting with Excel workbook When you're building an Excel add-in

- Excel on the web has a payload size limit for requests and responses
  of 5MB. RichAPI.Error will be thrown if that limit is exceeded.
- A range is limited to five million cells for get operations.

Based on your description, it looks to me that you are hitting payload size issue. I would suggest to check the data before calling context.sync(). Split the operation into smaller pieces as needed. Be sure to call context.sync() for each sub-operation to avoid those operations getting batched together again.

Another tip is to leverage RangeAreas to strategically update cells within a larger range. See Work with [multiple ranges simultaneously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-multiple-ranges) in Excel add-ins for more information.